# SKLearn TF-IDF to drop numbers?

Tags: scikit-learn, tf-idf

I'm doing text analysis, and I want to disregard 'words' that are just numbers. Eg. from the text "This is 000 Sparta!" only the words 'this', 'is' and 'Sparta' should be used. Is there a way to do this? How?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The default token pattern for `TfidfVectorizer` is `u'(?u)\\b\\w\\w+\\b'` which matches a word that has at least two word characters, i.e, `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`; You can modify the `token_pattern` to your needs, for instance, regex `(?ui)\\b\\w*[a-z]+\\w*\\b` makes sure it matches a word but contains at least one letter:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
tf = TfidfVectorizer(token_pattern=u'(?ui)\\b\\w*[a-z]+\\w*\\b')
​
text = ["This is 000 Sparta!"]
tfidf_matrix =  tf.fit_transform(text)
feature_names = tf.get_feature_names() 
​
print(feature_names)
[u'is', u'sparta', u'this']
```

​

Answer (score 4):

Look how it is implemented in official documentation [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/bicluster/plot_bicluster_newsgroups.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-bicluster-plot-bicluster-newsgroups-py).
All numbers are treated as one feature #NUMBER