# SKLearn TF-IDF Vectorizer how to skip words which have only numbers

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tfidfvectorizer

In SKLearn TF-IDF Vectorizer how do I keep alphanumeric words, but still skip words which are just numbers from the result?

Example almost like
[SKLearn TF-IDF to drop numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45981037/sklearn-tf-idf-to-drop-numbers)

However, if I use that regex - `(?ui)\\b\\w*[a-z]+\\w*\\b`, then I miss a lot of words like `zzz1-p1-zzz`

```
   corpus = [
        """zzz1-p1-zzz kubelet-wrapper[1977]: E0219 21:00:03.163475    1977 kubelet_volumes.go:154] \
            Orphaned pod "1e6da6ca-9def-11eb-b6b3-248a0794fa16" found, \
            but volume paths are still present on disk : There were a total of 3 errors similar to this. Turn up verbosity to see them."""
    ]

    vectorizer =TfidfVectorizer(token_pattern=u'(?ui)\\b[a-z-0-9]{4,}\\b',stop_words='english')  
    print('token_pattern:', vectorizer.token_pattern)

    vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)

    print(vectorizer.get_feature_names())
```

Current output

```
['163475', '1977', '1e6da6ca-9def-11eb-b6b3-248a0794fa16', 'disk', 
'e0219', 'errors', 'kubelet-wrapper', 'orphaned', 'paths', 'present',
 'similar', 'total', 'turn', 'verbosity', 'volume', 'zzz1-p1-zzz']
```

In the expected output, I do not wish to have `[1977,163475]`. I am not able to get the right regex for this

Answer (score 0):

Something like `(?!^[0-9]*$)` should work. This regex is the negation of "only digits".

Comment: Thanks; but that was giving no selection

Answer (score 0):

Technically I got something like this

```
vectorizer =TfidfVectorizer(token_pattern=u'(?ui)\\b[a-z][a-z-_0-9]{4,}|[0-9][a-z-_]{4,}\\b',stop_words='english')
```

Ouput

```
['9def-', 'b6b3-248a0794fa16', 'e0219', 'errors', 'kubelet-wrapper', 
'kubelet_volumes', 'orphaned', 'paths', 'present', 'similar', 'total', 
'verbosity', 'volume', 'zzz1-p1-zzz']
```

But I stuck with

```
vectorizer =TfidfVectorizer(token_pattern=u'(?ui)\\b[a-z][a-z-_0-9]{4,}\\b',stop_words='english')  
    print('token_pattern:', vectorizer.token_pattern)
```

Ouput

```
['b6b3-248a0794fa16', 'e0219', 'errors', 'kubelet-wrapper', 
'kubelet_volumes', 'orphaned', 'paths', 'present', 'similar', 'total', 
'verbosity', 'volume', 'zzz1-p1-zzz']
```